# How to work with Spring based form tag Date field?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, date

In my Spring application have jsp and form.

demo.jsp have one field `<form:input path="fromDate"/>`

And in my DemoForm have field `private Date fromDate;`,

When we store the value Null value storing...

My Question Is their any direct tag for Store the date in my spring supplied jsp tag.

other wise give me other alternate way..

Comment: I don't think its an issue with the tag. If your date is in the format DD-MM-YYYY, binding will happen automatically.

Comment: please provide more code i.e. your controller snippet.

Comment: Why null value coming when dubug..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the custom editor for the Date in your controller. Please try below code.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    df.setLenient(false);
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(df, true); // second argument 'allowEmpty' is set to true to allow  null/empty values.
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```